# How can I include an articleBody that is outside of the Article's itemscope?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I am attempting to modify existing HTML to include microdata using the Schema.org ontology.

Due to historic reasons, the HTML is not structured in a proper hierarchy that would easily allow the use of a single `itemscope`. In this example, the `articleBody` is actually separate from the `name`, `author`, and `datePublished`.

Here is a simple snippet to demonstrate an example of the problem and what I am trying to accomplish:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
      <h1 itemprop="name">Example News Article Page</h1>
      <span itemprop="datePublished">January 1, 2014</span>
      <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
    </div>

    <div itemprop="articleBody">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Obviously, the `articleBody` is not contained within the `itemscope` and therefore any parser would have no clue what that fragment is related to.

I attempted to use `itemref` to relate the `articleBody` to the actual `NewsArticle`.

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" id="myArticle">
      <h1 itemprop="name">Example News Article Page</h1>
      <span itemprop="datePublished">January 1, 2014</span>
      <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
    </div>

    <div itemprop="articleBody" itemref="myArticle">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This didn't appear to work. I also modified it to use variations of adding `itemscope`, redeclaring the `itemtype`, etc... Unfortunately, none of those methods seemed to work. I'm assuming that this is simply not the correct usage of `itemref`.

I also made an attempt with `itemid`. For example:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" itemid="foo">
      <h1 itemprop="name">Example News Article Page</h1>
      <span itemprop="datePublished">January 1, 2014</span>
      <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
    </div>

    <div itemprop="articleBody" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle" itemid="foo">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum
        </p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Again, this didn't seem to work. In both cases, Google's Structured Data Tester doesn't show the expected results (the body is either non-existent or not related to the article, itself) and Yandex gives me the error `unable to determine affiliation of these fields. There are two possible reasons: this fields are incorrectly placed or an orphan itemprop attribute is indicated`

I'm not quite sure if it's possible to do what I am attempting to accomplish. The reason that I am attempting to do things this way is that we have a *lot* of pre-existing and complex HTML templates along with a massive amount of JavaScript. Attempting to refactor or otherwise modify existing HTML, aside from just adding annotations, could quickly become a nightmare.

**Is it possible to do what I am attempting to implement? If so, can you show me a simple code example or point out the flaw in my attempts?**

Thanks!

Update

I got the articleBody to work using `itemref`. The problem I had is that I was using the reference backwards -- that is I was referring to the `NewsArticle` from the `articleBody` instead of the other way around. Here is my snippet:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div itemref="content"  id="articleHeader" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
      <h1 itemprop="name">Example News Article Page</h1>
      <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
    </div>

    <div id="content" itemprop="articleBody">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum blah blah blah
        </p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be scalable. Let's say I want to reference the `copyrightHolder` which is labeled in the footer of the page. If I add another `itemref` to my article, then it appears to blow up and the `articleBody` is not related to the `NewsArticle`. E.g.

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div itemref="content"  itemref="company" id="articleHeader" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
      <h1 itemprop="name">Example News Article Page</h1>
      <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
    </div>

    <div id="content" itemprop="articleBody">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum blah blah blah
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="company" itemprop="copyrightHolder">
        My Awesome Company
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I was on the right track. The problem I had was that I attempted to declare `itemref` multiple times, each time for another `id`. According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-microdata-20110405/#attr-itemref), `itemref` actually expects a [space-separated list](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-microdata-20110405/#unordered-set-of-unique-space-separated-tokens) of `id` values.

Here is the working example:

```
<html>
  <body>

    <div itemref="content company" id="articleHeader" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/NewsArticle">
      <h1 itemprop="name">Example News Article Page</h1>
      <span itemprop="author">John Doe</span>
    </div>

    <div id="content" itemprop="articleBody">
        <p>
          Lorem Ipsum blah blah blah
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="company" itemprop="copyrightHolder">
        My Awesome Company
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I use with json-ld?